# python mutiprocessing.pool.imap() alternatives

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, jobs

I running an issue when using pool, so I need to change it with some alternative.

I trying `joblib.Parallel` but it works more similar to `map`, not `imap` but I hope to get results like a iterator and being able to start handling results as soon the first one available, not waiting others to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pool.apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async) with a callback function, which will be called for each one as it finishes.

The callback can only take one argument, so if your functions return more than one thing, your callback function will need to be aware of this and unpack the arguments (it will receive one argument, a tuple, containing the return values of the function.)

Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time


def f(x):
    time.sleep(1/(x * 100))
    return x**2

def callback(value):
    print(value)

# in Python 3.3 you can use a context manager with the pool.
pool = Pool(3)
for value in range(10):
    pool.apply_async(f, (value,), callback=callback)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: pool have an issue on my system, so I can't use it. And looking for something to replace.

Comment: What's your system?  Are you sure it's because pool isn't working, or could it be something else?

Comment: I pretty sure it's a pool problem. System - Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I'm using Cinnamon Mint and it works fine... what version of Python are you using?  I changed my example code to work with earlier versions of Python.